# Huggingface Transformers giving blank output after finetuning on validation set

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, huggingface, huggingface-datasets

I’m trying to finetune BLIP on visdial dataset (An Image QA dataset). However, just for testing purposes, I took 200 Image Question answer pair and fine-tuned them while calculating the output loss which is near about 1.40.

But after the fine-tuning process is completed, whenever I’m giving the model an Image and a question from the same set from where it has been fine-tuned, it is not producing any output. On printing the output variable I observed the tensor is filled with zeros.

Dataset link: https://huggingface.co/datasets/jxu124/visdial/viewer/jxu124--visdial/train

Model link: https://huggingface.co/Salesforce/blip-vqa-base

Here is my fine-tuning code:

```
class visDial_dataset(Dataset):
def __init__(self, dataset, processor):
    self.processor = processor
    self.dataset = dataset

def __len__(self):
    return len(self.dataset)

def __getitem__(self,idx):
    item = self.dataset[idx]
    
    encodings = self.processor(images = item["images"], text = item["questions"], padding = "max_length", return_tensors = "pt")
    labels = self.processor(text = item['answers'], padding = "max_length", return_tensors = "pt").input_ids

    encodings['labels'] = labels
    encodings = {k:v.squeeze() for k,v in encodings.items()}

    return encodings


from torch.utils.data import DataLoader

train_dataset_object = visDial_dataset(modified_val_set, processor)
train_dataloader = DataLoader(train_dataset_object, shuffle=True, batch_size=2)

import torch

optimizer = torch.optim.AdamW(model.parameters(), lr=1e-2)


model.train()

for epoch in range(3):
  print("Epoch:", epoch)
    for idx, batch in enumerate(train_dataloader):

    input_ids = batch.pop("input_ids").to(device)
    pixel_values = batch.pop("pixel_values").to(device)
    labels = batch.pop("labels").to(device)
    attention_mask = batch.pop('attention_mask').to(device)

    outputs = model(
                input_ids=input_ids,
                pixel_values=pixel_values,
                labels=labels,
                attention_mask = attention_mask
               )

    loss = outputs.loss
    print("Loss:", loss.item())
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
    optimizer.zero_grad()

 model.eval()
```

## This 48 is just a random number I chose as an index to feed the 48th Image and Question to the model

```
 rand = 48
 print(questionList[rand])
 print(ansList[rand])
 pil_img_list[rand]
```

## Inference

```
encoding = processor(images=pil_img_list[rand], text=questionList[rand],return_tensors="pt").to(device)
outputs = model.generate(**encoding)
print(processor.decode(outputs[0], skip_special_tokens=True))
```

Please help me identify where I’m making a mistake. I’m new to the Transformers.